# What does it mean for points to be picked uniformly and independently?

Tags: terminology, contest-math

I saw a which said that points were picked uniformly and independently. I have a feeling this is important for the solution but I am not sure what they mean by *uniformly* and *independently*. Any help would be appreciated. I will post the original question here.

Question:
Four points are chosen uniformly and independently at random in the interior of a given circle. Find the probability that they are the vertices of a convex quadrilateral.

Note: I am not looking for a solution to the problem, just for clarification on what uniformly and independently mean.

Comment: "Uniformly" means without applying any preference to a particular part of a region. So, if you were choosing uniformly amongst a discrete set of options, say the numbers $1$ through $10$, you're just as likely to choose $5$ as you are $2$: the probability of drawing any given number is $\frac{1}{10}$. "Independently" here really just means that the last point you chose has no impact on any future point you choose. So, say that $A_1$ is your first choice and $A_2$ your second choice. The probability of drawing both is $\Pr[A_1 \cap A_2] = \Pr[A_1] \cdot \Pr[A_2]$.

Comment: Uniformly in this case means the probability density is a constant $\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$.  Independent means the choice of any one point has no effect on the choice of any other point.

Comment: @Matt.P This should be an answer.

Comment: Thank you. That really clears it up.

Comment: I know you weren't looking for the solution to the problem; but if you ever do look for it, you'll find it here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html

Comment: Thanks, Arnaud. I'll rewrite it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a picture helps more than words and formulas, at least for the term "uniform":

[image]

"Independent" means that a single one of the random points does not care where the other points are, but its position is picked *independently* of the others, as if they were not there. E.g. to be not independently chosen, a point could try to avoid being placed at a position where many other points have been placed already. This can give a uniform pattern, but they are not chosen independently (now the order in which the points are chosen matters).

---

As Hurky said, when one (mostly a non-mathematician) says "random", what he means most of the time includes the properties *uniform and independent*. E.g. throwing a dice gives uniformly and independently chosen random numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Let's see what the same experiment might look like when one of the properties is missing:

- **not uniform**: the dice is biased, e.g. it was manipulated to show the $6$ more often (on average) than any other number.
- **not independent**: the dice "has a memory". E.g. it tries to not show the same number as on the last throw. Sometimes people think that because there was no $6$ for a long time, the probability that there will come a $6$ is now higher. This can only be true if the dice does not generate independent numbers, which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reformulating an earlier comment I made as an answer.

"Uniformly" means without applying any preference to a particular part of a region. So, if you were choosing uniformly amongst a discrete set of options, say the numbers $1$ through $10$, you're just as likely to choose $5$ as you are $2$: the probability of drawing any given number is $1$ in $10$.

"Independently" here really just means that the last point you chose has no impact on any future point you choose. So, say that $A1$ is your first choice and $A2$ your second choice. The probability of drawing both is $\Pr[A1 \cap A2]= \Pr[A1] \cdot \Pr[A2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer is that the four random points follow the "obvious" distribution — the distribution you would have assumed if you were the sort of person who didn't realize you were assuming a probability distribution.

A more precise statement is:

- That $Q_i$ is chosen *uniformly* means that for any subregion $S$ of the interior of the circle, $\mathbf{P}(Q_i \in S)$ is proportional to the area of $S$
- That the four points are chosen *independently* means that for any four regions $S_i$, you have
  $$ \mathbf{P}(Q_1 \in S_1 \text{ and } \ldots \text{ and } Q_4 \in S_4)
  = \mathbf{P}(Q_1 \in S_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathbf{P}(Q_4 \in S_4) $$